# What is the difference between "offen" and "geöffnet"?

Tags: synonym

Are they interchangeable? If not, could you please provide some usage examples?

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. What did you dictionary say about that? Which example(s)/situation lead to your question that you felt unsure what is what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are often interchangeable, but *geöffnet* implies that somebody or something has actively opened, whereas *offen* simply states that it's not closed (maybe never has been).

*Offen* is used in all kinds of contexts, *geöffnet* mostly for shops “wir haben geöffnet Mo-Fr 9-18 Uhr”. Also it can describe the actual process of opening: “das Tor hat sich geöffnet” means we've just watched the gate open or at least that previously it was closed; this can be a bit of a dramatic statement, whereas “das Tor steht offen” is more of a boring description that the gate happens to be open.

Comment: This suggests that "opened" might be a more precise translation of "geöffnet".

Comment: @Spencer -- Except you'd say a store is "open from 9 to 6" not "opened from 9 to 6". There might be other exceptions but that's probably the best way to think about it; offen  = "open", geöffnet  =  "opened".

Answer (score 1):

> Die Dose Katzenfutter ist offen. Ich habe sie geöffnet.

Das letztere ist das Ergebnis eines Prozesses, das erste nicht unbedingt.

> Der Ausgang der Wahl ist noch offen.

Die Wahl wird zwar eröffnet aber nicht geöffnet. Die Urne wird geöffnet (nicht: Die Urne wird offen).

Offen heißt auch *nicht verdeckt* und kann auch nicht mit *geöffnet* substituiert werden:

> Er zeigte offen seine Antipathie.

> Die Beleidigungen und Drohungen gingen in eine offene Feldschlacht über.

Comment: English question, english answer?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Wenn Du eine konkrete Frage hast, immer raus damit, oder empower Dich selbst mit DeepL o. dgl. Meine Haltung zur Frage, Deutsch auf Englisch zu lernen, kannst Du in den einschlägigen Metadiskussionen nachlesen.

Comment: I have a feeling that if I were the OP, and capable of understanding either the comment above, or the answer given, that I probably would not have needed to ask the question.

Comment: @user02814: Und basiert das Gefühl auf irgendwelchen Indizien oder ist es pure Phantasie? Wieso sollte mich Dein Gefühl interessieren? Was für ein Interesse könnte jmd., der praktisch kein Deutsch kann, haben, den Unterschied zw. offen und geöffnet erfahren zu wollen?

Comment: @userunknown: I understand your opinion about language learning (learn the new language with explanations only in the new language). And I understood that on German.SE it is common sense to answer a question in the language of the question. Otherwise it would always be a duplicate if the question is asked first in english and secondly in german. Just these are treated as two related, not duplicated questions.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Schau, niemand verbietet Dir die Frage auf Englisch zu beantworten, wenn Dir danach ist. Mein Englisch ist nicht grottenschlecht, aber die Feinheiten des Ausdrucks wie im Deutschen erreiche ich bei weitem nicht. Wenn ich Podcasts zu Themen auf Englisch höre, die nicht mein täglich Brot sind (Programmieren) und wenn der Text von einem Muttersprachler kommt, bemerke ich auch recht deutlich die Beschränktheit meines Wortschatzes. Daher antworte ich bevorzugt auf Deutsch. Du kannst Dich gerne der Mehrheit anschließen.